# Viewing CloudWatch log metric filters for each individual log stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a number of EC2 instances, each running a separate instance of my application. All log files are being streamed into CloudWatch, using the hostname of each EC2 instance as the *log stream* name, so I have multiple *log streams* for each *log group*.

I want to create a custom metric for each of my EC2 instances using data from the CloudWatch logs. I've set up a *metric filter*, but this aggregates the data across all the *log streams* in my *log group*. **I want to be able to see this metric for each individual EC2 instance** (i.e. separate by *log stream*). Is this possible? Or if not, how would I achieve this? (The only method I can think of would be to use a different *log group* for each instance, which isn't ideal).

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. If you are using CloudFormation to deploy your instances and/or log streams, the best way I have found to do this is by appending a reference to your instance ID at the end of your metric name.

```
"MetricTransformations": [
{
    "MetricValue": "1",
    "MetricNamespace": "myNamespace",
    "MetricName": { "Fn::Join": [ "", [ "myMetric - ", { "Ref" : "InstanceID" }] ] }
}
```

What would be nice is if you could somehow associate your logstreams as a dimension in a single metric, rather than creating one for each instance.